# Sorting numbers from a random method in Java

Tags: java, javafx

Whenever I click refresh in my program here, it will generate 5 random numbers from between 1 to 13 and display it in the form of cards on screen. I'm using JavaFx for that. I cannot figure out the second thing, which is when I click the Sort button then the program should take the current set of random numbers and show the cards from lowest to highest.

```
public class Cards extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);

}

public static int mycard() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int  n = rand.nextInt(13) + 1;
    return n;
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setTitle("Cards Layout");

    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.setHgap(10);
    pane.setVgap(5);


    // creates button
    Button refresh = new Button("Refresh");
    HBox button = new HBox(10);
    button.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    button.getChildren().add(refresh);
    pane.getChildren().add(refresh);

    //Create sort button
    Button sort = new Button("Sort");
    HBox button1 = new HBox(10);
    button1.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    button1.getChildren().add(sort);
    pane.getChildren().add(sort);

    // creates random card images and adds them to pane
    Image img = new Image("image/card/"+mycard()+".png");
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);

    pane.add(imgView, 1, 0);

    Image img2 = new Image("image/card/"+mycard() +".png");
    ImageView imgView2 = new ImageView(img2);
    pane.add(imgView2, 2, 0);

    Image img3 = new Image("image/card/" +mycard()+ ".png");
    ImageView imgView3 = new ImageView(img3);
    pane.add(imgView3, 3, 0);

    Image img4 = new Image("image/card/" +mycard()+".png");
    ImageView imgView4 = new ImageView(img4);
    pane.add(imgView4, 4, 0);

    Image img5 = new Image("image/card/" +mycard()+".png");
    ImageView imgView5 = new ImageView(img5);
    pane.add(imgView5, 5, 0);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    refresh.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            imgView.setImage(new Image("image/card/" +mycard()+".png"));
            imgView2.setImage(new Image("image/card/" +mycard()+".png"));
            imgView3.setImage(new Image("image/card/" +mycard()+".png"));
            imgView4.setImage(new Image("image/card/" +mycard()+".png"));
            imgView5.setImage(new Image("image/card/" +mycard()+".png"));
        }
    });
    sort.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            imgView.setImage(new Image("image/card/" + "1.png"));
            imgView2.setImage(new Image("image/card/" + "2.png"));
            imgView3.setImage(new Image("image/card/" + "3.png"));
            imgView4.setImage(new Image("image/card/" + "4.png"));
            imgView5.setImage(new Image("image/card/" + "5.png"));
//Cannot figure out what to do here ^
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more particular about the problem? Is it while sorting numbers, or while displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `myCard()` you need to add the randomly generated number to a `List`. When you click on refresh you need to clear that list (`myList.clear()`). When you click on sort you need to first sort that list and then access the items in the list by index from `0` to `myList.size()`.

If you add your images to a `List`, too, you can use the same index to match image with number / imageResource.

Since you have a fixed number of cards you could also use an Array (but if you plan on reusing code for implementations with more cards I'd use a List)